# Setting elements relative to the left corner of image

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I'm working on the floor plan view in Xamarin.Forms and I'm having a problem with setting the elements relative to the left corner of the image control. I want to do that because my database stores the coordinates of each element connected to the specific map (counted from the left corner of image). It is necessary to use this layout because user can zoom and move the map. Here is some code from Xaml:

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="286" WidthRequest="994">                                                        
                                 <Image HeightRequest="286" WidthRequest="994" Source="test.jpg" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1"/>                                                                
                            <Label Text="Test" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,-1,1" TranslationX="300" TranslationY="200"></Label>
                             </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: You want keep the label's position on the left corner of the image control? And it won't change even if user zoom or move the map? And left top corner or left bottom corner?

Comment: I want to place the image in center of the view and place the labels on the left top corner after that i want to move them into right positions which are stored in database (labels' top and left margin counted in pixels).